# The probability of having rain is 1/4. The probability of having a test is 5/6.

Tags: probability

a) What is the probability of having no rain but having a test?

b) What is the probability of having rain or having a test?

How would I go about solving these questions? Do I just multiply the fractions? (eg. *No rain* = 3/4, *test* = 1/6, **3/4 * 5/6**) Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: These are independent events.

Comment: Are the two events independent? If so, you can multiply the appropriate probabilities. If not, the problem does not have enough information. I'd say logically, they should be independent unless there's a chance of flood or something like that. Note that either rain or test is the same as NOT (no rain and no test).

Comment: Actually, the OP mentions that the events are independent right at the end.

Comment: That was an edit I made. I forgot to specify. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You omitted the critical condition that rain and test are independent!

If we assume independence, we can use the standard formulas like
$$P(\text{test} \& \text{rain}) = P(\text{test}) \times P(\text{rain})$$

(which is, in fact, the *definition* of independence).

Now you can use the [Inclusion–exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for part b.

Comment: How would I go about solving part a)? I understand part b) now.

Answer (score 3):

Let $R=$ event such that it rains; let $T=$ event s.t. you have a test.

Assuming $R$ and $T$ are independent:
$$\Pr\underbrace{[R^c \cap T]}_{\text{(not rain) and test}}=\underbrace{\Pr[R^c] \times\Pr[T]}_{\text{as they're independent}}=[1-\Pr(R)] \times\Pr[T]=?$$

Also, $\Pr[R \cup T]=\Pr[R]+\Pr[T]-\underbrace{\Pr[R \cap T]}_{\text{What do we know about this, given R and T are independent?}}=??$

Comment: This seems like a very long way to say $\frac{1}{4}*\frac{5}{6}$

Comment: @JohnFernley Numbers aren't really that important; anyone can type $1/4*5/6$ into a calculator; it's the **concept** that's important--understanding stuff rather than mindlessly regurgitating/memorising is what separates man from machine!

Answer (score 1):

P(test or rain)=P(test)+P(rain)-P(test and rain)